# ES6 reduce returning 1 array item instead of 2

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I've been playing with the reduce function a lot lately. I came across this issue, where my function is only returning a single array item from the reduce instead of 2 (there are 2 items in the array)

This is my function:

```
const pages = await getPosts.reduce((post) => {

  const postRoutes = {
    [`/blog/${post.slug}`]: {
      page: "/blog/post",
      query: { 'postSlug': post.slug }
    }
  };

  return postRoutes;

});
```

Comment: From MDN [`reduce()` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce): *"The `reduce()` method applies a function against an accumulator and each element in the array (from left to right) to reduce it to a **single value**."* It sounds like you may be meaning to use a different method, as `reduce()` is used when you want to reduce an array to just *one value*.

Comment: Go to https://mdn.com and read about reduce. You are not using it correctly

Comment: Hi @dileet, could you give some example on the posts data from getPosts method and your expected result. Perhaps, you want to use `.map` instead of `.reduce`.

Comment: I agree with @bhoo-day in that it seems like you're after [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead of `reduce()`: *"The `map()` method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array."*

Comment: @bhoo-day I tried .map, but it's giving me back an array. I need an object like ```{ '/blog/testpost': { page: '/blog/post', query: { postSlug: 'testpost' } }  '/blog/testposttwo': { page: '/blog/post', query: { postSlug: 'testpostwot' } } }```

Comment: @TylerRoper with .map I get back ```[ [0]: { '/blog/testpost': { page: '/blog/post', query: { postSlug: 'testpost' } } }, [1]: { '/blog/testposttwo': { page: '/blog/post', query: { postSlug: 'testposttwo' } }} ]```

Comment: Misunderstanding, I thought you were trying to make an array of objects. In that case, you *do* want `reduce()`. SamVK's answer below is likely your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)'s callback takes two argument: the accumulator and the current value. You need to spread the accumulated data, plus the new data.

It also takes an initial value as its second argument, in this case an empty object.

```js
const example = [{ slug: 'alpha'}, {slug: 'beta'}].reduce((posts, post) => {
  const postRoutes = {
    [`/blog/${post.slug}`]: {
      page: "/blog/post",
      query: { 'postSlug': post.slug }
    }
  };
  return {...posts, ...postRoutes };
}, {});

console.log(example);
```